# Split each after 32 bits of 128 bit input in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to do 128 bit manipulation in Python, to split the 128 bit after 32 bit

```
var = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF # var may take any value from 0x0 to  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I have tried the

```
n = 8 # for 32 bit splitting
[var[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(var), n)]
```

But there is no built-in length operator to find the length for `long` variable. I researched bitarray module, I don't want to use bit array in my code, is there any thing in pythonic way?

Expected output would be `[0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF]`.

Comment: Do you mean `[0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFFFF]`? And are you declaring `var` with quotes?

Comment: No, I just edited my question please look into it

Comment: Can you use python3 instead of python2?

Comment: Trengo Thanks !! Good to know, I will switch to python 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use bit shifting (`>>`) and bitwise AND (`&`):

```
In [10]: [(i >> x) & 0xFFFFFFFF for x in reversed(range(0, 128, 32))]
Out[10]: [4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295]
```

where `i` is your integer. The resulting list will have 4 elements (because *128 / 32* is *4*).

In your case the result is 4 equal numbers (*4294967295*, because *4294967295* is *0xFFFFFFFF* in hex).

This works well for a known number of bits (32), but I'd rather use a helper function (following the same logic as above):

```
def split_bits(value, n):
    ''' Split `value` into a list of `n`-bit integers '''
    mask, parts = (1 << n) - 1, []
    parts = []
    while value:
        parts.append(value & mask)
        value >>= n
    parts.reverse()
    return parts
```

In action:

```
In [14]: split_bits(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 32)
Out[14]: [4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295]

In [15]: [format(i, 'X') for i in _] # show corresponding hex representations
Out[15]: ['FFFFFFFF', 'FFFFFFFF', 'FFFFFFFF', 'FFFFFFFF']

In [16]: split_bits(0b1000100110101011, 4)
Out[16]: [8, 9, 10, 11]

In [17]: [format(i, 'b') for i in _] # show corresponding binary representations
Out[17]: ['1000', '1001', '1010', '1011']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. is it possible to find the length of long Interger? I may need it for future, is there any possible way?

Comment: @Jonny yes, see [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length).

Comment: I have already tried it, but I am puzzled its throwing this error TypeError: descriptor 'bit_length' requires a 'int' object but received a 'long'.

Comment: @Jonny hmm, what's the version of your Python interpreter?

Comment: Python2 has two types for integer values (`int` and `long`). `long.bit_length` works (only on longs). [Python 3 doesn't have `long`s](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) and `int.bit_length` works for both.

Comment: @ vaultah , python version 2.7 and I have edited my problem statement please look into it

Comment: @Jonny I just realized my code produced parts in reverse order, I updated my answer.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but splitting a negative value in this way produces an endless loop.
`split_bits(-1)`
Due to the way that Python represents numbers.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to work with numbers instead of stirng

```
var = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
[(var & (0xFFFFFFFF << 32*i)) >> (32*i) for i in range(4)]
```

eventually you can conver number to string hex representation

```
format(n, 'x')
```

Comment: Thankew so much farincz. I have edited my problem statement please look into it